# How to specify classpath loading order in a JAR manifest file

Tags: java, ant, jar

I'm making a JAR file using Ant, but I need to specify the classpath loading order for the JAR file generated in the Manifiest file.

The reason for this is because some of the dependencies I have use different version of another library, and I need to make sure that the latest one is loaded. This is easy using Eclipse interface, but I'm not sure how to do this with Ant.

This is what I have now, for the JAR task:

```
<target depends="build-project" name="jar">
            <!-- Get the timestamp -->  
            <set.timestamp/>
            <!-- Create our own manifest file for our JAR -->
            <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${username} - ${company.name}"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="some.package.Main"/>
                <attribute name="Class-path" value=". ${lib.list}"/> 
                <attribute name="Implementation-Version" 
                    value="${major.version.number}.${minor.version.number}.${revision.number}"/>   
                <attribute name="Built-Date" value="${current.time}"/>                 
            </manifest>

            <jar whenmanifestonly="fail" destfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}_${major.version.number}.${minor.version.number}.${revision.number}.jar" manifest="MANIFEST.MF">
</target>
```

Now this is the Classpath property:

```
<manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${jar.name}_${major.version.number}.${minor.version.number}.${revision.number}.jar">
   <classpath refid="manifest.classpath" />
</manifestclasspath>
```

And this is the manifest.classpath:

```
<!-- Manifest classpaht -->
<path id="manifest.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib">
          <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
</path>
```

To me it looks like I?l have to define each library manually one by one above, instead of using a wildcard...but will that order be matained afterwards?

Thanks!
Alejandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the classpath, you can duplicate jars in that path, much like you can duplicate directories in `$PATH`. It's sloppy, but it's not bad:

```
PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin"
```

The `/bin` directory is specified twice, but that doesn't matter. If I specify `ls`, The first instance of `/bin` in my `$PATH` will find it. The last instance of `/bin` in my `$PATH` doesn't do anything. No real harm done with the duplication.

If you need to specify your classpath that certain jars must be first, then specify what you need first. If `$PATH` contains that particular jar name again, it doesn't matter:

```
 <path id="manifest.classpath">
     <pathelement location="${first.jar}"/>
     <pathelement location="${second.jar}"/>
     <fileset dir="${manifest.jars.dir}"/>
</path>
```

Even if `${first.jar}` and `${second.jar}` are in that `${manifest.jars.dir}`, it doesn't matter. They'll still be picked up first in your path, and ignored later in your path.

Now, you can do this:

```
<manifestclasspath property="manifest.path">
    <pathelement location="."/>
    <classpath refid="manifest.classpath"/>
</manifestclasspath>
```

And finally:

```
<jar destdir="....">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Class-path" value="${manifest.path}"/>
        ...
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Comment: That seemed to work, although pathelement is not allowed within manifestclasspath. In any case, it pointed me to the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the the classpath in the manifest will be defined with the entries ordered in the same order you provided them. I know it works like this in Maven, and pretty sure the same is in Ant, so what you can do is provided the "critical" entries first - and then put the wildcard, hence providing the order needed - while not manually defining all the required dependencies.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work, have a look at @David W. answer, it is quite OK, but thanks!